# How to show that normal distribution is a second order approximation to any distribution around the mode?

Tags: normal-distribution, econometrics, approximation

How can I show that normal distribution is a second order approximation to any distribution around the mode?

Comment: The Laplace approximation comes to mind : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace%27s_method

Comment: Depending on what you mean by "second order approximation," the statement is false.  If you are referring to density functions, then counterexamples include any distribution that does not have a differentiable density at its mode.  If you are referring to CDFs, then counterexamples include all distributions of random variables that have nonzero probability of equaling their mode.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider an arbitrary probability distribution $p(\theta)$. We want to approximate the distribution around the mode $\hat{\theta} = argmax \log p(\theta)$. We perform a second order Taylor expansion around $\hat{\theta}$ in log space and we obtain
$$ \log p(\theta) = \log p(\hat{\theta}) + \frac{1}{2} (\theta-\hat{\theta})^T \underbrace{\left( \nabla \nabla^T \log p(\hat{\theta})\right)}_{=: \psi} (\theta-\hat{\theta}) + O(\theta^3) $$
Where $\psi$ is the hessian matrix. Note that the first order term disappears as we are at a maximum and hence the first derivative is zero there. This is very similar to a Gaussian pdf in normal space, in fact
$$ p(\theta) \approx p(\hat{\theta}) \cdot \exp(- \frac{1}{2}(\theta - \hat{\theta})^T(-\psi) (\theta - \hat{\theta}))$$

Then we can define the Laplace approximation $q$ of $p$ as
$$ q(\theta) = \mathcal{N}(\theta, \hat{\theta}, -\psi^{-1})$$
It should be clear that this is proportional to the second order Taylor expansion. May also note that the hessian at the mode is symmetric and negative definite, hence $-\psi$ is symmetric and positive definite.

Comment: Should the LHS of your equation be $\log p(\theta)$ rather than $\log p(\delta)$?

Comment: Yeah introducing the $\delta$ was unnecessary, changed it.

Comment: Second order Taylor expansions do not necessarily exist.